# How do I handle vectors and matrices with 1D arrays as their elements?

Tags: numpy, linear-algebra, matrix-multiplication

I want to simulate a quantum system with three components.

I have a 'vector' of three elements corresponding to the individual wave function with N points of the three spin components. Each element is an 1D array so the 'vector' array has the shape 3xN.

I have 3 by 3 matrix operators with cells containing a operator array of N points. The matrix has the shape 3x3xN.

I want to be able to able to carry out regular linear algebra operations. For example, I want the matrix exponential to work the same way. The exponential of a diagonal matrix is just a diagonal matrix of the exponential of the elements on the diagonal so

```
A = ([1,2]  0    0
       0  [2,4]  0
       0    0  [3,6])

exp(A) = ([e^1,e^2]    0        0
              0    [e^2,e^4]    0
              0        0    [e^3,e^6])
```

Is there an elegant way to do this in Python?

I have tried doing this with regular NumPy arrays but it becomes too complicated when broadcasting different shapes together.

Comment: Are the non diagonal elements always 0?

Comment: Not always. Essentially, I'm looking for a way to carry out the matrix operations and then be able to subsitute the arrays back in afterwards.

Comment: Is there a problem with using an Nx3x3 numpy array? This could be used directly by scipy.linalg.expm to compute a matrix exponential

Comment: @mpw2 I have considered it but it would require changing a lot of the code I have already written so it's my final option.

Comment: How would you define those linear operations? From the example (but it is not very convenient that the only example you gave is a particular case, here a diagonal matrix. For example, the question you got is related to the fact that we can't guess from your example what would you call the exponential of a matrix. Pretty sure, since you insist on linear algebra, that you refer to generalized exponential, not to numpy `np.exp` function, that is element-wise exponential. But diagonal matrix are the sole case where there is no difference between both, and you choose this example)

Comment: From what you said, it seems that what you want to do is just perform regular linear algebra operations, but on a bunch of N 3x3 matrix and N 3 vectors, instead of one by one. I mean, there is not dependency among the last axis "plane", is there? `linearAlgebraOp([[v1a, v1b], [v2a, v2b], [v3a, v3b]], [[[mat11a, mat11b], [mat12a, mat12b], ...]], ..., [...[mat33a,mat33b]]]) is just the same as 2 independant `linearAlgebraOp(va, mata)` and `linearAlgebraOp(vb, matb)`. Right?

Comment: @zaphod, you can write a few functions to convert to and from your current "matrix" representation, and wrap linear algebra operations in something like `to_my_matrix(scipy.linalg.expm(to_np_array(mat1)))`

Comment: I guess this is even the reason why @mpw2 asked about axis order. If you had N×3x3 matrix and N×3 vectors instead, many numpy operation would already work as you wish, for example, the expm quoted. If the only problem is that you don't want to change the existing code for the shape N×3x3, N×3, then you can simply move the axis before calling the linear algebra functions. See `np.moveaxis`

Comment: @EmilioSilva No need to write functions for that. `np.moveaxis(M,0,2)` and `np.moveaxis(M,2,0)` will do.

Comment: @chrslg That's really helpful. I will give it a go now.

Comment: arrays with a mix of list and scalar elements has to be `object` dtype, and is little better than a list (of lists).  Most processing will occur a list comprehension speeds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to be more explicit, here is how (if I understood correctly what your last axis is, that is just a way to perform N times a linear algebra operation; which is how numpy usually treat, on the contrary, the first axes), you can use `np.moveaxis` for that.

For example, the expected result of exponential (again, if I understood correctly), can be obtained this way

```py
np.moveaxis(scipy.linalg.expm(np.moveaxis(M,2,0)),0,2)
```

That is you move the last axis in the first position: `np.moveaxis(M,2,0)` is a N×3×3 array. `expm` perform N times the exponential, once for each of the N 3x3 matrix, and return N 3x3 arrays, corresponding to the N results.
Since what you want is a 3x3xN array, you can move the first axis of the result back to the last position.

Note that `np.moveaxis` barely does anything. It just changes the `strides` of the array, which impact how data are accessed. It doesn't allocate any new memory (it is the same data), it doesn't move any data. `np.moveaxis(M,2,0)[0,1,2]` is the same element, by another name, as `M[1,2,0]` (I mean not the same "value", the same data in memory; `np.moveaxis(M,2,0)[0,1,2]=15` actually changes the value of `M[1,2,0]`.
So, in short, it costs nothing or almost so.

But that won't mean that you can move axis, and then just perform any linear algebra on the N×3×3 matrix and N×3 vectors as you would on 3x3 matrix and 3-vectors. Most numpy operations work that way, but not all.
And sometimes it is impossible.

Take the `@` matrix-vector multiplication, for example. It couldn't work, because it is ambiguous.
`A@B` is a matrix-matrix multiplication if A and B are 2D-arrays. It is a matrix-vector multiplication if A is a 2D array and B a 1D array.

But what if A is a 3D array and V a 2D array?
In numpy spirit, we use the extra axes for "vectorization". But must this be understood as N 2D-2D arrays (with always the same V)? Or N 2D-1D multiplication? It is almost the same, you would say. Since, after all, a matrix-matrix multiplication is, by definition, just M matrix-vector multiplication. But the "extra" dimension in that case is the last one, not the first one.

So, in short, it is ambiguous. And chosen definition for `@` with more than 2 axes per operand in numpy is not the one you want here.

That being said, you can use other methods.
For example, you can add another 1-sized dimension to your vector, so that it is treated by `@` as a 2D (with only 1 column, which, in math, is the same as a vector, but not exactly in numpy, for example, not in this case),

```
# move axis of M to have a N×3×3 array (aka N 3x3 matrix)   moveaxis
# move axis of V to have a N×3 array (aka N vectors)        moveaxis
# add a dimension V to have N×3×1 array (aka N 3x1 matrix)  [:,:,None]
# perform N matrix-matrix multiplication  (N (3×3)@(3×1))   @
# result is N×3×1 array
# remove the last axis to get a N×3 array                   [:,:,0]
# move back axis to get a 3×N array
MV = np.moveaxis((np.moveaxis(M,2,0) @ np.moveaxis(V,1,0)[:,:,None])[:,:,0], 0, 1)
```

You can also do that in a simpler way using `einsum` (shorter at least. But it takes some head scratching to understand full `einsum`)

```py
MV = np.einsum('ij...,j...->i...', M,V)
```

Matrix-matrix multiplication on the other hand, works like `expm` example. That is, if you had two `N×3×3` matrices, then just using @ would simply perform N multiplications on 3x3 matrices.
Since what you have are `3x3×N` matrices, just move axis to go back in the easy case, and moveaxis of the result back, like for `np.expm`

```py
np.moveaxis(np.moveaxis(A,2,0) @ np.moveaxis(B,2,0), 0,2)
```

Or, there again, `einsum` (but in that case, that is not necessary, since the general `moveaxis(op(moveaxis(...)))` trick works.

```py
np.einsum('ij...,jk...->ik...',A,B)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a few modifications.

First, your array should be uniform:

```py
import numpy as np

A = np.array([[[1,2], [0,0], [0,0]],
              [[0,0], [2,4], [0,0]],
              [[0,0], [0,0], [3,6]]])

>>> A
array([[[1, 2],
        [0, 0],
        [0, 0]],

       [[0, 0],
        [2, 4],
        [0, 0]],

       [[0, 0],
        [0, 0],
        [3, 6]]])
```

Second, the matrix operation you are looking for is `scipy.linalg.expm`:

```py
import scipy

B = scipy.linalg.expm(np.array([[1, 0, 0], [0, 2, 0], [0, 0, 3]]))

>>> B
array([[ 2.71828183,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  7.3890561 ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        , 20.08553692]])
```

Last, `expm` expects a square array in the last two dimensions, so you need to manipulate your array a bit:

```
A1 = np.transpose(A, (2, 0, 1))
A2 = scipy.linalg.expm(A1)
A3 = np.transpose(A, (1, 2, 0))

>>> A1
array([[[1, 0, 0],
        [0, 2, 0],
        [0, 0, 3]],

       [[2, 0, 0],
        [0, 4, 0],
        [0, 0, 6]]])

>>> A2
array([[[  2.71828183,   0.        ,   0.        ],
        [  0.        ,   7.3890561 ,   0.        ],
        [  0.        ,   0.        ,  20.08553692]],

       [[  7.3890561 ,   0.        ,   0.        ],
        [  0.        ,  54.59815003,   0.        ],
        [  0.        ,   0.        , 403.42879349]]])

>>> A3
array([[[  2.71828183,   7.3890561 ],
        [  0.        ,   0.        ],
        [  0.        ,   0.        ]],

       [[  0.        ,   0.        ],
        [  7.3890561 ,  54.59815003],
        [  0.        ,   0.        ]],

       [[  0.        ,   0.        ],
        [  0.        ,   0.        ],
        [ 20.08553692, 403.42879349]]])
```

Comment: Or `transpose`, indeed:D

Comment: Thank you for the answer but this doesn't answer my question. I am trying to find the best way of dealing with using arrays as the elements of arrays and vectors.

Answer (score 0):

Making your array:

```
In [101]: A = np.empty((3,3),object); A[:]=0    
In [102]: A[[0,1,2],[0,1,2]] = [np.arange(3) for _ in range(3)]    
In [103]: A
Out[103]: 
array([[array([0, 1, 2]), 0, 0],
       [0, array([0, 1, 2]), 0],
       [0, 0, array([0, 1, 2])]], dtype=object)
```

can't exp all:

```
In [104]: np.exp(A)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'exp'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[104], line 1
----> 1 np.exp(A)

TypeError: loop of ufunc does not support argument 0 of type numpy.ndarray which has no callable exp method
```

`np.vectorize` or `np.frompyfunc` can apply a function individually.  But note the change in the offdiagonals:

```
In [105]: np.frompyfunc(np.exp, 1,1)(A)
Out[105]: 
array([[array([1.        , 2.71828183, 7.3890561 ]), 1.0, 1.0],
       [1.0, array([1.        , 2.71828183, 7.3890561 ]), 1.0],
       [1.0, 1.0, array([1.        , 2.71828183, 7.3890561 ])]],
      dtype=object)

In [106]: np.frompyfunc(lambda x:2*x+1, 1,1)(A)
Out[106]: 
array([[array([1, 3, 5]), 1, 1],
       [1, array([1, 3, 5]), 1],
       [1, 1, array([1, 3, 5])]], dtype=object)
```

but don't need this for operators like this

```
In [107]: 2*A+1
Out[107]: 
array([[array([1, 3, 5]), 1, 1],
       [1, array([1, 3, 5]), 1],
       [1, 1, array([1, 3, 5])]], dtype=object)
```

Ignoring the offdiagonals will require some further cover utilities for example test for arrays:

```
In [110]: np.frompyfunc(lambda x:np.exp(x) if isinstance(x,np.ndarray) else x, 1,1)(A)
Out[110]: 
array([[array([1.        , 2.71828183, 7.3890561 ]), 0, 0],
       [0, array([1.        , 2.71828183, 7.3890561 ]), 0],
       [0, 0, array([1.        , 2.71828183, 7.3890561 ])]], dtype=object)

In [112]: np.frompyfunc(lambda x:2*x+1.1 if isinstance(x,np.ndarray) else x, 1,1)(A)
Out[112]: 
array([[array([1.1, 3.1, 5.1]), 0, 0],
       [0, array([1.1, 3.1, 5.1]), 0],
       [0, 0, array([1.1, 3.1, 5.1])]], dtype=object)
```

This kind of thing can be generalized.  Just don't expect performance like that of compiled numeric numpy code.